# Optional.orElse() change the return type?

Tags: java, java-8

I need help on understanding the Optional.orElse() method's return type.
Please take a look at the simple method below.  It is supposed to return a `String`. If the `arg` is not null, then the `map` function changes the `arg` to `toUpperCase` and returns an `Optional` object. Then how this `Optional` object is changed to a `String` in this case? Because there are no compiler errors in this method. Is this is done by `orElse()`? Because if I remove orElse(), it shows a return type miss match error. What is the magic behind that changing the data type?

```
private String process(String arg) {

    return Optional.ofNullable(arg).map(String::toUpperCase).orElse("value from orElse");

}
```

I am really confused about how the orElse() changes the return type here. And what is the exact return type of orElse()

Comment: "how the orElse() changes the return type here" consider this: `new Integer(53).toString()` with `toString`, the return type is `String`. without it, it is `Integer`. How does `toString` change the return type? (the signature of `orElse` is available in the documentation)

Comment: You have looked at the javadoc of Optional.orElse(), haven't you?

Comment: @Sören         yes, but how does adding it change the return type in the method? This is what I do not understand.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Optional<String>.orElse() *has* a return type of String.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T- ?

Comment: @Sören         But, when there is a value in the ´arg´ it should return Optional instead of a String.  Isn't it? In that case, it violates the return type of the method which is String.

Comment: @azro           doc says ´Return the value if present, otherwise return other.´ When there is a value in the ´Optional´ object, how does it change from ´Optional´ to ´String´ here? This is what I do not understand.

Comment: No the value is actually the "value" wrapped by the Optional class, if you open the Optional class implementation you can see it

Comment: Optional.ofNullable(arg) -> return "new Optional <> (value)", then map apply the toUpperCase method into the 'value' wrapped by the class Optional and return the new value again wrapped by an Optional, then you call orElse which basically returns either the value if it is not null, otherwise the argument that you passed

Comment: @dreamcrash    So you say "orElse which basically returns either the value if it is not null," Do You mean the value is returned without wrapping the Optional ? Which is String. ??

Comment: yes, it will be the value resulted from apply the function toUpperCase to the args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The expression

   ```
   Optional.ofNullable(arg)
   ```

   is returning an object of type `Optional<String>`, as defined in the javadoc of [`Optional.ofNullable(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-), where in this case the generic variable `T` is of type `String`.
2. The method call

   ```
   .map(String::toUpperCase)
   ```

   on the `Optional<String>` object will return a `Optional<String>` object. This is defined in the javadoc of [`Optional.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-). In this particular case, the generic variable `T` is still of type `String` and the new generic variable `U` for this specific method is `String` as well, since the method being called ([`String.toUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--)) is returning a `String`.
3. The final method call

   ```
   .orElse("value from orElse")
   ```

   will "terminate" or "consume" the `Optional<String>` instance. It will either return the value inside the `Optional<String>` instance (which is the original value but in uppercase), or it will return the given fallback value `"value from orElse"`, as specified in the javadoc of [`Optional.orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-).

So in order you have the following types:

```
Optional<String> - from ofNullable()
Optional<String> - from map()
String           - from orElse()
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I understood now how it happens.